# Decode base64Url in Java

Tags: java, base64, base64url

https://web.archive.org/web/20110422225659/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications

talks about base64Url - Decode

---

a modified Base64 for URL variant exists, where no padding '=' will be used, and the '+' and '/' characters of standard Base64 are respectively replaced by '-' and '_'

---

I created the following function:

```
public static String base64UrlDecode(String input) {
    String result = null;
    BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
    try {
        result = decoder.decodeBuffer(input.replace('-','+').replace('/','_')).toString();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

it returns a very small set of characters that don't even resemble to the expected results.
any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn't use `sun.misc.BASE64Decoder` because it is internal Sun/Oracle code (not part of J2SE) and may disappear at any time. The class [Base64](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) in [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) should provide you with all the functionality you need.

Comment: my question is how to properly decode a base64url string in java. and thanks i'll try apache commons

Comment: @Benjamin, wow, I didn't realize `BASE64Decoder` was a Sun class, internal or otherwise. I wonder why they broke with their own naming convention. +1

Comment: @BenjaminMuschko Might be nice to clarify that is it specifically in [Apache Commons _Codec_](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) for those that don't realise it is a link in your comment! :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `replace('_','/')`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

With the usage of `Base64` from Apache Commons, who can be configured to URL safe, I created the following function:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public static String base64UrlDecode(String input) {
    String result = null;
    Base64 decoder = new Base64(true);
    byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decode(input);
    result = new String(decodedBytes);
    return result;
}
```

The constructor `Base64(true)` makes the decoding URL-safe.

Comment: idle curiosity, why make it that verbose if you could just do this? `return new String(new Base64(true).decode(input));`

Answer (score 89):

Java8+

```
import java.util.Base64;


return Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
```

Comment: If you don't like trailing '=' (padding), then use: Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(str.g‌​etBytes(UTF_8))

Comment: @kiedysktos do you have an example sequence? Table `The "URL and Filename safe" Base 64 Alphabet` in does not allow `/` in [RFC 4648](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4648.txt) which getUrlEncoder() uses

Comment: EDIT: OK, I was using `getEncoder()` instead of `getUrlEncoder()`, my fault

Answer (score 51):

[Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications) encoding is part of the JDK since Java 8. [URL safe encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-5) is also supported with [java.util.Base64.getUrlEncoder()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html#getUrlEncoder--), and the "`=`" padding can be skipped by additionally using the [java.util.Base64.Encoder.withoutPadding()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#withoutPadding--) method:

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;

public String encode(String raw) {
    return Base64.getUrlEncoder()
            .withoutPadding()
            .encodeToString(raw.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}
```

Comment: The resulting string still contains equal signs. That's not URL safe, is it?

Comment: Use Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(str.getBytes(UTF_8))

Answer (score 8):

In the Android SDK, there's a dedicated flag in the `Base64` class: `Base64.URL_SAFE`, use it like so to decode to a String:

```
import android.util.Base64;
byte[] byteData = Base64.decode(body, Base64.URL_SAFE);
str = new String(byteData, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 6):

Guava now has Base64 decoding built in.

https://google.github.io/guava/releases/17.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html

Answer (score 5):

```
public static byte[] encodeUrlSafe(byte[] data) {
    byte[] encode = Base64.encode(data);
    for (int i = 0; i < encode.length; i++) {
        if (encode[i] == '+') {
            encode[i] = '-';
        } else if (encode[i] == '/') {
            encode[i] = '_';
        }
    }
    return encode;
}

public static byte[] decodeUrlSafe(byte[] data) {
    byte[] encode = Arrays.copyOf(data, data.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < encode.length; i++) {
        if (encode[i] == '-') {
            encode[i] = '+';
        } else if (encode[i] == '_') {
            encode[i] = '/';
        }
    }
    return Base64.decode(encode);
}
```

Comment: Warning: Trailing = characters get swallowed!

Answer (score 3):

Right off the bat, it looks like your `replace()` is backwards; that method replaces the occurrences of the first character with the second, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

@ufk's answer works, but you don't actually need to set the `urlSafe` flag when you're just decoding.

> [urlSafe is only applied to encode operations. Decoding seamlessly
>   handles both modes.](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#Base64%28int,%20byte%5B%5D,%20boolean%29)

Also, there are some static helpers to make it shorter and more explicit:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils;

public static String base64UrlDecode(String input) {
  StringUtils.newStringUtf8(Base64.decodeBase64(input));
}
```

Docs

- [newStringUtf8()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/StringUtils.html#newStringUtf8%28byte%5B%5D%29)
- [decodeBase64()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#decodeBase64%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 1):

This class can help:

```
import android.util.Base64;

public class Encryptor {

    public static String encode(String input) {
        return Base64.encodeToString(input.getBytes(), Base64.URL_SAFE);
    }

    public static String decode(String encoded) {
        return new String(Base64.decode(encoded.getBytes(), Base64.URL_SAFE));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the answer is already there, but still, if someone wants...

```
import java.util.Base64; 

public class Base64BasicEncryptionExample {  

    public static void main(String[] args) {  

       // Getting encoder  
       Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getUrlEncoder();  
       // Encoding URL  
       String eStr = encoder.encodeToString
                               ("http://www.javatpoint.com/javatutorial/".getBytes());  
       System.out.println("Encoded URL: "+eStr);  

       // Getting decoder  
       Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getUrlDecoder();  
       // Decoding URl  
       String dStr = new String(decoder.decode(eStr));  
       System.out.println("Decoded URL: "+dStr);  
    }  
}
```

Took help from: https://www.javatpoint.com/java-base64-encode-decode

Answer (score 0):

`Base64.getUrlEncoder()` already using `-`, `_` instead of `+`, `/`.

See:

java-1.8.0/src.zip!/java/util/Base64.java

`java.util.Base64`

```java
    /* Returns a Base64.Encoder that encodes using the URL and Filename safe type 
     * base64 encoding scheme.
     * Returns: A Base64 encoder.
     * */


    public static Encoder getUrlEncoder() {
         return Encoder.RFC4648_URLSAFE;
    }

...

    /*
     * It's the lookup table for "URL and Filename safe Base64" as specified in 
     * Table 2 of the RFC 4648, with the '+' and '/' changed to '-' and '_'. This 
     * table is used when BASE64_URL is specified.
     * */

    private static final char[] toBase64URL = {
        'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',
        'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
        'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
        'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '-', '_'
    };

...

    static final Encoder RFC4648_URLSAFE = new Encoder(true, null, -1, true);
```

Answer (score -1):

In Java try the method `Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString()` from Commons Codec library for encoding.