# Onedrive API read files on given Link

Tags: onedrive

I want to create project with Microsoft Cognitive Services working with Onedrive API.

Scenario is : User will give me an Onedrive link and my API will go files on that folder.

Is it possible?

If so, where can I find more documentation about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to leverage the `shares` API using an encoded version of the OneDrive Link.

> GET ../v1.0/shares/{sharingTokenOrUrl}

Where `sharingTokenOrUrl` in your case is the URL encoded in the following manner:

1. First, use base64 encode the URL.
2. Convert the base64 encoded result to unpadded base64url format by
   removing = characters from the end of the value, replacing / with _
   and + with -.)
3. Append u! to be beginning of the string.

As an example, to encode a URL in C#:

```cs
string sharingUrl = "https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1231244193912!12&authKey=1201919!12921!1";
string base64Value = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sharingUrl));
string encodedUrl = "u!" + base64Value.TrimEnd('=').Replace('/','_').Replace('+','-');
```

Check out [this documentation](https://dev.onedrive.com/shares/shares.htm) for a complete description of the `shares` endpoint.

Comment: Do you know what is the same encoding and base64 value for javascript

Comment: See if the answer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641303/base64url-in-java) is what you need