# Base 64 encoding issue.(unexpected plus marks)

Tags: java, base64, urlencode

I am facing below issue after encoding the below string using base64

before encoding 
special/char!@#\"\"'\"$\"%^&*(\")=+{}|[:<>?,./'~`hdsgajakhdg

after encoding(base64)
c3BlY2lhbC9jaGFyIUAjXCJcIidcIiRcIiVeJiooXCIpPSt7fXxbOjw+PywuLyd+YGhkc2dhamFraGRn

this encoding string has plus marks(+). 
when I use this value in the URL I am facing issues because of that. How to avoid this to use this value in URL. Any idea ?

Comment: You use the variant of Base64 that is [URL-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications), known as base64url, as shown in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38287029/5221149).